# AttributeError when using object.__setattr__

Tags: python, object, setattr

What's wrong with the last three lines?

```
class FooClass(object):
    pass 
bar1 = object() 
bar2 = object() 
bar3 = object() 
foo1 = FooClass() 
foo2 = FooClass() 
foo3 = FooClass() 
object.__setattr__(foo1,'attribute','Hi')
foo2.__setattr__('attribute','Hi')
foo3.attribute = 'Hi'
object.__setattr__(bar1,'attribute','Hi')
bar2.attribute = 'Hi'
bar3.attribute = 'Hi'
```

I need an object having a single attribute (like foo) should I define a class (like FooClass) just for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`object` is [built-in type](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html), so you can't override attributes and methods of its instances.

Maybe you just want a [`dictionary`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) or  [`collections.NamedTuples`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
>>> d = dict(foo=42)
{'foo': 42}
>>> d["foo"]
42

>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'], verbose=True)
>>> p = Point(11, y=22)     # instantiate with positional or keyword arguments
>>> p[0] + p[1]             # indexable like the plain tuple (11, 22) 33
>>> x, y = p                # unpack like a regular tuple
>>> x, y (11, 22)
>>> p.x + p.y               # fields also accessible by name 33
>>> p                       # readable __repr__ with a name=value style Point(x=11, y=22)
```

Comment: l = list(); l.attr = 7; AttributeError... I guess you're right!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add new attributes to an `object()`, only to subclasses.

Try `collections.NamedTuple`s.

Besides, instead of `object.__setattr__(foo1,'attribute','Hi')`, `setattr(foo1, 'attribute', 'Hi')` would be better.